# Adding totals; Budget app, vanilla JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Thank you for being a light at the end of JavaScript tunnel!! :)

This is an simple Budget App that tells you how much to expect to spend at the market before check out. The problem is that it have being extremely difficult for me to add the totals to get "Today's today". I have try many things but nothing seems to work. I have a big headache for trying.

Thank you for your answers, you rock!

(please add an item to see what I talking about)

[Market Budget App](https://tools4you.neocities.org/Budget.html)

```
<script>
    //Array with items to buy from Market
    var array = [{
            item: "Tomato",
            id: 0,
            qty: 2,
            price: .58,
            total: 0
        },
        {
            item: "Orange",
            id: 1,
            qty: 5,
            price: .20,
            total: 0
        },
        {
            item: "Avocado",
            id: 2,
            qty: 12,
            price: .69,
            total: 0
        },
        {
            item: "Pizza",
            id: 3,
            qty: 1,
            price: 10.00,
            total: 0
        }
    ];

    let btns = document.getElementsByClassName('displayBtn');
    let table = document.getElementById("table");
    let total = 0;

    //Display info in the table
    for (i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        btns[i].innerHTML = array[i].qty;
        table.rows[i + 1].cells[1].innerHTML = array[i].item;
        table.rows[i + 1].cells[2].innerHTML = array[i].price;
        table.rows[i + 1].cells[3].innerHTML = (array[i].qty * array[i].price).toFixed(2)
        total = total + (array[i].qty * array[i].price);            
        table.rows[5].cells[1].innerHTML = total.toFixed(2);

    };

    //Add or subtract one item quantity.
    function counter(n, x) {
        if (x == 1) {
            array[0].qty = array[0].qty + n;
        } else if (x == 2) {
            array[1].qty = array[1].qty + n;
        } else if (x == 3) {
            array[2].qty = array[2].qty + n;
        } else {
            array[3].qty = array[3].qty + n;
        }

        totals()
    };

    //Display new Totals
    function totals() {
        for (i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            btns[i].innerHTML = array[i].qty;
            array[i].total = (array[i].qty * array[i].price).toFixed(2);
            table.rows[i + 1].cells[3].innerHTML = (array[i].qty * array[i].price).toFixed(2);                       
        };
        total = array[0].total+array[1].total+array[2].total+array[3].total
        table.rows[5].cells[1].innerHTML = total;
    }


</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you plus string by string, you need use `parseInt` for qty and `parseFloat` for price before adding values.

JSFilddle https://jsfiddle.net/viethien/8zwoev72/

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Market Budget App</title>
    <style>
        * {
            box-sizing: border-box;
        }

        body {
            margin-left: 50px;
        }

        .btn {
            float: left;
        }

        .btn.Minus {
            border-radius: 25px 0 0 25px;

        }

        .btn.Plus {
            border-radius: 0 25px 25px 0;
        }

        .inline {
            display: inline;
        }

        table,
        th,
        td {
            border: 1px solid black;
            width: 500px;
            height: 30px;
            text-align: center;
        }
        tfoot{
            font-weight: bolder;
            color: rgb(53, 77, 53);
            background-color: rgb(250, 234, 242);
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>

    <h2>Market Grocery Budget </h2>
    <table id="table">
        <tr>
            <th>Qty:</th>
            <th>Items:</th>
            <th>Price:</th>
            <th>Totals</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><button class="btn Minus" onclick="counter(-1,1)">-</button>
                <button class="btn qty displayBtn"></button>
                <button class="btn Plus" onclick="counter(1,1)">+</button>
            </td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td id="total1"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><button class="btn Minus" onclick="counter(-1,2)">-</button>
                <button class="btn qty displayBtn"></button>
                <button class="btn Plus" onclick="counter(1,2)">+</button>
            </td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td id="total2"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><button class="btn Minus" onclick="counter(-1,3)">-</button>
                <button class="btn qty displayBtn"></button>
                <button class="btn Plus" onclick="counter(1,3)">+</button>
            </td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td id="total3"></td>

        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><button class="btn Minus" onclick="counter(-1)">-</button>
                <button class="btn qty displayBtn"></button>
                <button class="btn Plus" onclick="counter(1)">+</button>
            </td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td id="total4"></td>
        </tr>
        <tfoot>
            <tr>
              <td colspan="3">Today's total--->>
              </td>
              <td id="TOTAL"></td>
            </tr>
          </tfoot>
    </table>



    <script>
        //Array with items to buy from Market
        var array = [{
                item: "Tomato",
                id: 0,
                qty: 2,
                price: .58,
                total: 0
            },
            {
                item: "Orange",
                id: 1,
                qty: 5,
                price: .20,
                total: 0
            },
            {
                item: "Avocado",
                id: 2,
                qty: 12,
                price: .69,
                total: 0
            },
            {
                item: "Pizza",
                id: 3,
                qty: 1,
                price: 10.00,
                total: 0
            }
        ];

        let btns = document.getElementsByClassName('displayBtn');
        let table = document.getElementById("table");
        let total = 0;

        //Display info in the table
        for (i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            btns[i].innerHTML = array[i].qty;
            table.rows[i + 1].cells[1].innerHTML = array[i].item;
            table.rows[i + 1].cells[2].innerHTML = array[i].price;
            table.rows[i + 1].cells[3].innerHTML = (array[i].qty * array[i].price).toFixed(2)
            total = total + (array[i].qty * array[i].price);            
            table.rows[5].cells[1].innerHTML = total.toFixed(2);
            
        };

        //Add or subtract one
        function counter(n, x) {
            if (x == 1) {
                array[0].qty = array[0].qty + n;
            } else if (x == 2) {
                array[1].qty = array[1].qty + n;
            } else if (x == 3) {
                array[2].qty = array[2].qty + n;
            } else {
                array[3].qty = array[3].qty + n;
            }

            totals()
        };
        //Display new Totals
        function totals() {
            for (i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
                btns[i].innerHTML = array[i].qty;
                array[i].total = (array[i].qty * array[i].price).toFixed(2);
                table.rows[i + 1].cells[3].innerHTML = (parseInt(array[i].qty) * parseFloat(array[i].price)).toFixed(2);                       
            };
            total = parseFloat(array[0].total)+ parseFloat(array[1].total)+ parseFloat(array[2].total)+ parseFloat(array[3].total)
            table.rows[5].cells[1].innerHTML = total;
        }



        
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your answers!!  It works perfectly!!  Beer are on me!!! :)

Answer (score 0):

Javascript

```
var array = [{
            item: "Tomato",
            id: 0,
            qty: 2,
            price: .58,
            total: 0
        },
        {
            item: "Orange",
            id: 1,
            qty: 5,
            price: .20,
            total: 0
        },
        {
            item: "Avocado",
            id: 2,
            qty: 12,
            price: .69,
            total: 0
        },
        {
            item: "Pizza",
            id: 3,
            qty: 1,
            price: 10.00,
            total: 0
        }
    ];

var todaysTotal = 0

for (const item of array) {
  todaysTotal += (item.qty * item.price);
}

console.log(todaysTotal)
```

Output

```
20.439999999999998
```

Hopefully that helps!